# WEB API using BreezeJS Works Locally But Not On Production Web Server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze, single-page-application

I have built an SPA using some John Papa examples as the basis for the design.. When I run the application locally it works fine, however as soon as I place it onto a Windows Server 2003 environment I get this ""message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http:" .. I have copied over the dll's published to Server and still I get this issue?

Can anyone assist me ?

Comment: Have you tried to hit the end points without Breeze to make sure they are functional?

Comment: I have scrapped the whole usage of Breeze, it seems best implemented with an ORM such as EF .. I feel back to simple AJAX and created my own caching mechanism .. Thanks for the help and sorry for the delayed reply...